# Mamp won't start apache

Tags: macos, apache, mamp

I'm having trouble running my Mamp. Out of the blue it the apache-part stopped working.

I've had this kind of quirks before with MAMP and I would reinstall it. But now I've set it up with multiple virtual hosts, lots of databases I want to keep & Reinstalling will remove all my databases :S

So this is the log from my console:

```
10/05/13 08:56:20,423 coreservicesd[32]: Application App:"MAMP" [ 0x0/0x7d07d]  @ 0x0x7fc6214c7c80 tried to be brought forward, but isn't in fPermittedFrontASNs ( ( ASN:0x0-0x20c20c:) ), so denying.
10/05/13 08:56:20,423 WindowServer[126]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to MAMP, psn 0x0-0x7d07d, securitySessionID=0x186a5, err=-13066
10/05/13 08:56:20,433 authexec[13342]: executing /bin/sh
```

I've been googling for this, but didn't find anyone with a problem like it, nor a solution. I've tried stopping mac's built-in apache(but it just isn't running) so that won't help.

Comment: Have you just installed the java update?

Comment: The "failing to be brought forward" error seems to be a red herring. That error doesn't actually seem to cause any problems and can be ignored. There's something else going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why Apache might not start (and there are other answers here in StackExchange too).

But my MAMP Apache was unable to start out of the blue, just like yours, and it turns out that I had renamed the Apache Document Root folder a few days earlier. Just open MAMP, click on Preferences, select the Apache tab, and then make sure the Document Root folder exists.